# Angularfire Seed Routes

Tags: routes, angularfire, ngroute

Is there a detailed example of how to modify the routes in the Angularfire seed?  Although it seems like it should be a straightforward edit of the routes.js and partial html pages I have not been able to do it this way. What am I missing?

Comment: It would help to include what you've tried so far and what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I fixed a few days back but I'm not sure what was wrong in the first place other than I wasted a day on it, came back the next day and I got it done in less than 10 minutes. I think it may have had to do with missing bower components, which I'm really not sure why they're not automatically installed with the angularfire seed . . .